# I want to return the client only once during service startup and use through out until the app restarted

Tags: c#, .net-core, singleton

I have a console .net core app where I am creating a client using `Singleton` scope using `ConfigureServices`.

My thought it will create once and all the future call server by this single client.

But my `GetClient` calls every time when ever I am making a call like `await _hubClient.GetClient();`

Can I return the client only once during service startup and use through out until the app restarted?

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IHubClient, HubClient>(x =>
                {
                    var requiredService = x.GetRequiredService<ILogger<HubClient>>();
                    return new HubClient(requiredService);
                });
            });

public interface IHubClient
{
    public Task GetClient();
}
public class HubClient : IHubClient
{
    private readonly ILogger<HubClient> _logger;

    public HubClient(ILogger<HubClient> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task GetClient()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        _logger.LogInformation("gets called every time");
        // code to return client
        return client;
    }
}
```

Call:

```
 public class Service : IInvocable
{
    private readonly IHubClient _hubClient;

    public Service(IHubClient hubClient)
    {
        _hubClient = hubClient;
    }
    public async Task Invoke()
    {
        await _hubClient.GetClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of the client in the GetClient method?

Comment: It's a IOT Hub Client, but in general, I want to return anything. Why it's invoked every time. Is Singleton works like this way only?